# How do you detonate sticky bombs in GTA V for PC?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

On the Xbox 360 you used to press left on the D-pad, but for the PC I've mashed everything and nothing seems to detonate them.

I also don't see anything in the controls menu that makes sense.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default the key is <kbd>G</kbd>. You can change it in the key bindings menu:

[image: Settings > Keybindings > Combat > Throw Grenade / Detonate Sticky Bombs]

Answer (score 1):

You can also shoot them if you get desperate. Of course, that will only detonate one at a time, unless they're on the same object.